# Forcing fsck to check more than one mount point at every boot?

Tags: boot, mount, 22.04, fsck

I want to force `fsck` to run before every boot on my 2 mount points (constant problems with the filesystem):

- /dev/nvme0n1p2
- /dev/nvme0n1p4

```
> mount | grep nvme0
/dev/nvme0n1p2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/nvme0n1p1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/nvme0n1p4 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

This is what my fstab looks like:

```
> more /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
#
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=c8da3896-602b-48a0-969f-d17e2d78ebcb /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
#
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=02B5-2A18  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
#
# /home was on /dev/nvme0n1p4 during installation
UUID=4fb469d5-6a3c-4153-9d27-8257d862bb99 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
#
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p3 during installation
UUID=1b1bb9f3-084a-4951-93ac-2c12dc9f15e3 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Note the PASS column, it is set to 1 for nvme0n1p2 and to 2 for nvme0n1p4.

- 0 – disabled
- 1 – higher priority and is checked first
- 2 – will be checked last

To force `fsck` after every system reboots I do the following:

- `sudo tune2fs -c 1 /dev/nvme0n1p2`
- `sudo tune2fs -c 1 /dev/nvme0n1p4`

To confirm the command is applied `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/nvme0n1p4`:

`Maximum mount count:      1`

However, on every boot, I see only the `nvme0n1p2` is being checked.

Why is the second mount point `nvme0n1p4` not being checked?

Note that `blkid` for some reason gives nothing for `nvme0n1p4`:

```
> blkid /dev/nvme0n1p4
>
```

For `nvme0n1p2` it gives the usual output:

```
> blkid /dev/nvme0n1p2
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="c8da3896-602b-48a0-969f-d17e2d78ebcb" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="ee3e65c7-d35e-4d6e-a856-55cda225dda3"
```

Comment: How did you determine the UUID of nvme0n1p4 if blkid doesn't provide it?

Comment: I read it from fstab, see above.